# Download file from an ASP.NET SOAP web service using php or Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have an ASP.NET SOAP web service, i have been using it for several calls from php and jquery AJAX but now i need to download files from the server. my php/jquery application is on wamp. The Web service and the application consuming it are hosted on different servers. APACHE AND IIS.
With this code, the file donloads but cannot open with pdf.
Thanks in advance. I have tried Jquery file download plugin too
This is my webservice code to download the file.

```
         System.IO.FileStream fs1 = null;
        fs1 = System.IO.File.Open(file_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] b1 = new byte[fs1.Length];
        fs1.Read(b1, 0, (int)fs1.Length);
        fs1.Close();
        return b1;
```

This is my JQuery code

```
 `                           
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", 
    "http://localhost:54761/EXT/ExternalSolicitorWebService.asmx/Download?
    file_path="+$(dat).data("payload"), true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
oReq.onload = function() {

  var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: $(dat).data("filetype").toLowerCase});
  var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = downloadUrl;
        a.download =  $(dat).data("filename");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  $(window).on('focus', function(e) {
    $(a).remove();
  });
};

oReq.send();
```